# Thunderbird: always sort emails by date

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

In Thunderbird, I have my messages sorted by date, in descending order. The newest message is on top. That is probably the most common setup.

Now my problem:
Very often, when I want to click on the newest email (first from top), it happens I click on the "From" header above, which causes the messages to be re-arranged and sorted according to "From" field. This drives me crazy.

Is it possible to "freeze" the headers (i.e. "From", "Subject", "Date", ..) and the sorting order ?

I only ever want to sort by date. If I click on "From" by mistake, I would like nothing to happen.

Is this possible ?

I am using Icedove (Thunderbird) 24.8.1 on Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[No Message Pane Sort](http://nompsort.sourceforge.net/index.html)

I haven't tried it and it says 2011 in the documentation so YMMV.

I have been frustrated by this many times, but I don't actually want to turn it off because once in awhile changing the sort order helps me find things.

Comment: This works great. Thanks so much. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: BTW, I suggest you try it. You can still sort by using `CTRL+click`

Comment: I just installed it to give it a try. It works on Thunderbird 31.2.0 as well. I had to use View->Sort By to change the sorting - to make sure it worked. You can also upvote my answer (in addition to accepting it) if you want to.

Comment: I tried, but I need 2 more points to be able to upvote.